# Keyframe Animation not working on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

So I have an animation I'm trying to play on my website: http://eayusi.design

It doesn't seem to be working on my iPhone, regardless of whatever browser I use.  I've added the -webkit- before the animation as suggested by other answers but that doesn't seem to be working. I would appreciate any help I can get guys. I am currently using an iPhone 6 on the latest iOS.

```
  html
  {
    font-size: 62.5%;
  }

  body
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
  }

  .glitch
  {
    position:relative;
    top: 40%;
    color: white;
  }

  .glitch:before, .glitch:after{
    content: 'Coming soon';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:black;
  }

  .glitch:before{
    left: 4px;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 #00ffea;
    animation: effect 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: effect 3s infinite linear;
    clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 38px, 0);
  }

  .glitch:after{
    left: -2px;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 tomato;
    animation: effect 2s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: effect 2s infinite linear;
  }

  @keyframes effect {
      0% {
        clip: rect(42px, 9999px, 44px, 0);
      }
      5% {
        clip: rect(12px, 9999px, 59px, 0);
      }
      10% {
        clip: rect(48px, 9999px, 29px, 0);
      }
      15.0% {
        clip: rect(42px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
      }
      20% {
        clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
      }
      25% {
        clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 55px, 0);
      }
      30.0% {
        clip: rect(86px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
      }
      35% {
        clip: rect(20px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
      }
      40% {
        clip: rect(26px, 9999px, 60px, 0);
      }
      45% {
        clip: rect(25px, 9999px, 66px, 0);
      }
      50% {
        clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 98px, 0);
      }
      55.0% {
        clip: rect(5px, 9999px, 46px, 0);
      }
      60.0% {
        clip: rect(82px, 9999px, 31px, 0);
      }
      65% {
        clip: rect(54px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
      }
      70% {
        clip: rect(28px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
      }
      75% {
        clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 69px, 0);
      }
      80% {
        clip: rect(23px, 9999px, 85px, 0);
      }
      85.0% {
        clip: rect(54px, 9999px, 84px, 0);
      }
      90% {
        clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
      }
      95% {
        clip: rect(37px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
      }
      100% {
        clip: rect(4px, 9999px, 91px, 0);
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes effect {
        0% {
          clip: rect(42px, 9999px, 44px, 0);
        }
        5% {
          clip: rect(12px, 9999px, 59px, 0);
        }
        10% {
          clip: rect(48px, 9999px, 29px, 0);
        }
        15.0% {
          clip: rect(42px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
        }
        20% {
          clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
        }
        25% {
          clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 55px, 0);
        }
        30.0% {
          clip: rect(86px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
        }
        35% {
          clip: rect(20px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
        }
        40% {
          clip: rect(26px, 9999px, 60px, 0);
        }
        45% {
          clip: rect(25px, 9999px, 66px, 0);
        }
        50% {
          clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 98px, 0);
        }
        55.0% {
          clip: rect(5px, 9999px, 46px, 0);
        }
        60.0% {
          clip: rect(82px, 9999px, 31px, 0);
        }
        65% {
          clip: rect(54px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
        }
        70% {
          clip: rect(28px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
        }
        75% {
          clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 69px, 0);
        }
        80% {
          clip: rect(23px, 9999px, 85px, 0);
        }
        85.0% {
          clip: rect(54px, 9999px, 84px, 0);
        }
        90% {
          clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
        }
        95% {
          clip: rect(37px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
        }
        100% {
          clip: rect(4px, 9999px, 91px, 0);
        }
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="glitch">Coming soon</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working on mobile by including:

```
.glitch:before, .glitch:after {
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/vWZpEj?editors=0100) is a Codepen that demonstrates it working on mobile. I made a couple other changes that are still in the Codepen, but this was the change that made it work correctly.

I was tinkering with your code based on [another post](https://css-tricks.com/glitch-effect-text-images-svg/) from CSS-Tricks where they got it working through SASS. To be completely honest, I'm not sure why it works since I don't have a ton of experience with clipping or masks, but it does.

Edit: Also note that the clip property has been depreciated. So it may be worth finding a replacement implementation that uses clip-path on elements inside of SVGs. I'll see if I can get an example created when I find some extra free time.

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes I saw that article too, I ended up avoiding it completely because I've never used SASS. But thank you so much, I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Of course! Just as a note, it's common courtesy to mark the most accurate answer as the Accepted Answer. 

Also, it's totally worth checking out SASS/LESS and other CSS preprocessors once you get comfortable working in CSS. They help quite a bit with organizing large projects and generating large sections of repeated code.